# Salesforce Email and tokens

Tags: email-template, dynamic-binding

So I inherited the Administration of Salesforce from a previous colleague. We use Salesforce tokens to dynamically populate Contact/Lead names, phone numbers and email address and Contact/Owner names, phone numbers and email address among other pieces of information.

For example our tokens for Full Name, Phone Number and Email Address look like this:

```
Sincerly,
{!Contact.OwnerFullName}
{!Contact.OwnerPhone}
{!Contact.OwnerEmail}
```

Depending on the user that is logged in and uses an email template containing these tokens, the information is dynamically populated with their information. It seems to be based on login.

However, some of my users are saying that the Tokens are not being populated with their information.

Is there a away that I can go about testing or finding out more information on these Tokens and figuring out why these work for some users but not others in my group?

Thanks
GB

Comment: So many reasons why this might happen. Two that come to mind include: owner field might be hidden, owner might not be visible to user (user sharing). Try logging in as the user having problem, and try using the record they were having problems with. Replicate exactly. Then see if they can see the owner field, and see the actual user record by clicking on the user's name.